# What does 就算这次做错也只是怕错过 mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, lyrics

I found this sentence in a song's lyrics => " 就算这次做错也只是怕错过 ". What does it mean?

Comment: Welcome to the site. As the [FAQ](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/faq#can-i-request-a-translation) says, please show that you did some research before asking for a translation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To translate directly:

> Even if making a mistake this time, it is still preferred for the fear of
>   missing the moment.

In other words, it means one would rather take this opportunity (perhaps once in a lifetime opportunity) to do something even if it means making a mistake.

For the full lyrics of this song 给我一首歌的时间 by Jay Chou, please refer to this [link](http://www.9ku.com/geci/176214.htm).

Answer (score 1):

1. 歌词并不遵守严格的中文语法
2. 这句话完整的句子应该是“就算这次做错（那也没有关系），（相比之下）更怕错过”

Comment: Hello and welcome, do you mind adding some more context and explanation?